# How do I check to see if a BST works in SML?

Tags: binary-search-tree, sml

Heyo! I'm trying to construct a Binary Search Tree in SML, and I want to check to see if it correctly constructs a tree. I think the code I have is correct as it does compile without any errors, but without a function to check, I can't be sure. I have a provided checker in my textbook, but I don't know how to apply it to the Binary Search Tree. Here's my code:

```
datatype 'data tree = 
    Empty 
  | Node of 'data tree * 'data * 'data tree;

fun makeBST nil L = Empty
  | makeBST (a::b) L = 
    let
      fun insert Empty a = Node(Empty,a,Empty)
        | insert (Node(left, root, right)) a = 
          if L(a, root) then 
            Node(insert left a, root, right)
          else
            Node(left, root, insert right a)
    in
      insert (makeBST b L) a
    end;
```

And here is the checker code:

```
fun isintree x Empty = false
  | isintree x (Node(left,y,right)) = 
    x = y orelse isintree x left orelse isintree x right;
```

Comment: which `interpreter` / `compiler` are you using? Does it give you any `REPL`?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a very good checker, since it doesn't check the ordering of the tree, or that all the elements you added are in there, or that nothing you didn't add is there.

Let's start with verifying that the tree really is a *search* tree.

A binary tree is a search tree if and only if

- it is empty, or
- both its subtrees are search trees, and

  - all nodes in the left subtree are ordered before its element, and
  - all nodes in the right subtree are ordered after its element

In order to check whether a predicate holds for all nodes of a tree, we can use

```
fun all_tree Empty _ = true
  | all_tree (Node (l, x, r)) pred = pred x
                                     andalso all_tree l pred
                                     andalso all_tree r pred
```

and then we can define

```
fun is_search_tree order Empty = true
  | is_search_tree order (Node (l, x, r)) = is_search_tree order l
                                            andalso is_search_tree order r
                                            andalso all_tree l (fn y => order(y, x))
                                            andalso all_tree r (fn y => order(x, y));
```

Next, we can check completeness by verifying that

- All elements in the list are in the tree, and
- all elements in the tree are in the list

Putting it all together:

```
(* This argument order makes this function more usable - 
you're more likely to want to look up different values in 
the same tree than the same value in different trees.*)
fun isintree Empty _ = false
  | isintree (Node(left,y,right)) x = 
       x = y
       orelse isintree left x
       orelse isintree right x;


fun test_list order ls =
    let val t = makeBST ls order
    in
        is_search_tree order t
        andalso all_tree t (fn x => List.exists (fn y => x = y) ls)
        andalso List.all (isintree t) ls
    end;
```

Test:

```
- test_list op< [];
val it = true : bool

- test_list op< [1];
val it = true : bool

- test_list op< [1,2,3];
val it = true : bool

- test_list op< [3,2,1];
val it = true : bool

- test_list op> [1,2,3];
val it = true : bool

- test_list op< [1,1];
val it = false : bool
```

Oops. What happened?

```
- makeBST [1,1] op<;
val it = Node (Empty,1,Node (Empty,1,Empty)) : int tree
```

There are duplicates in the tree.
Fixing this left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

After loading the program, you can try the following commands in REPL:

```
- val bst = makeBST [2,6,5,4,3] op <;
val bst = Node (Node (Empty,2,Empty),3,Node (Empty,4,Node #)) : int tree

- isintree 4 bst;
val it = true : bool

- isintree 5 bst;
val it = true : bool

- isintree 10 bst;
val it = false : bool
```